# Maximum number of keys for an AzureAD app registration

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

Is there a maximum number of keys that you can create for an azure activedirectory app registration? I am getting an error creating the 41st key.  Can this be changed?

Comment: I doubt it. Why do you have 40 keys? :D

Comment: The different keys are for different installed instances of the service application that I may want to disable independently.

Comment: Those could be separate apps then?

Comment: no.  That would make deployment very much more complex.

Comment: Don't do this for multi-tenancy please. The secret is not a security boundary, it's proof of ownership.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is no way to raise such limits, though you can try contacting support.

An alternative approach that would work is creating an Application + Service Principal for each deployment vs. creating a key for each deployment.
You can then still disable an individual deployment by deleting the app's key.
You can automate the creation of the app + SP + any required permission assignments through Azure AD Powershell or Azure Graph API/MS Graph API.

Comment: This is a reasonable solution.  Currently the application id is baked into to my service installation. This would mean I would have to make this into an installation parameter.  I will have to consider all this.  thanks for your solution.